# python3 - Main thread kills child thread after some timeout?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, time

I'm not sure it is doable with thread in python. Basically, I have a function which invokes  GDAL library to open an image file. But this can be stuck, so, after 10 seconds, if the file cannot be opened, then it should raise an exception.

```
import threading
import osgeo.gdal as gdal

def test(filepath):
    # After 10 seconds, if the filepath cannot be opened, this function must end and throw exception.
    # If the filepath can be opened before 10 seconds, then it return dataset
    dataset = gdal.Open(filepath)
    return dataset

filepath="http://.../test.tif"
t = threading.Thread(target = test, args = [filepath])
t.start()

# is there something called t.timeout(10)
# and if this thread cannot be finished in 10 seconds, it raises a RuntimeException?

t.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `multiprocessing` and `Queue` from `multiprocessing` to achieve what I wanted:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
from multiprocessing import Queue

q = Queue() 


TIME_OUT = 5

def worker(x, queue):
    time.sleep(15)
    a = (1, 5, 6, 7)
    queue.put(a)

queue = Queue()
process = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(5, queue,))
process.start()
# main thread waits child process after TIME_OUT
process.join(TIME_OUT)

if process.is_alive():
    print("Process hangs!")
    process.terminate()
    print("Process finished")

print(queue.qsize())
if queue.qsize() > 0:
    a, b, _, d = queue.get()
    print(a, b, d)
```